# Azure Team Services CI - Release Variable does not work

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I am trying to automate resource group creation with team services release.
I added azure resource group project to the solution and defined administratorLoginPassword variable as a secure string in json definition: [image: json definition]
Also I defined administratorLoginPassword variable at the environment level in release definition as the following: [image]
But when I run release it fails with the following reason:

> Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory
>   parameters: administratorLoginPassword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass that variable explicitly to the template script specifying its value in the **Override Template Parameters** text box, as follow:

```
-administratorLoginPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -String '$(administratorLoginPassword)' -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Anyway I would suggest to create a proper [azuredeploy.parameters.json file](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-acs-kubernetes/azuredeploy.parameters.json) where you store all the actual values for all the required template parameters, and pass this file to **Template Parameters** input of the Azure Resource Group Deployment task. This file could be manipulated during build/release by replacing the content with the values you need, avoiding entirely to play with special parameters of the build task.

The variables created in the Build/Release Definition are disregarded by the Azure Res. Group Deployment task unless you pass it over explicitly as shown above.